# How to run a report and simultaneousy load its data in background

Tags: c#, activereports

I created a report (Active Report) and run it. But the report window or report do not appear until the entire report has been loaded.

And I want that the report should open instantly as soon as I click "Show Report" button and data in that report should load in background.

```
private void ViwerGLactivityReport_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        try
        {
            ar = new ActiveReport();
            ar = LoadReport(wSession, ar, CurrentUserContext, StartDate, EndDate, accountstart, accountEnd, PostInvoiceDate, JournalIDInvoiceNo);
            ViwerGLactivityReport.Document = ar.Document;
            ar.Run();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            CusException cex = new CusException(ex);
            cex.Show(MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
}

   public ActiveReport LoadReport(NHSessionManager.SessionForWindows wSession, ActiveReport ar, M3.Globals.UserContext CurrentUserContext, DateTime StartDate, DateTime EndDate, double accountstart, double accountEnd, string PostInvoiceDate, string JournalIDInvoiceNo)
    {
        ar = new ActiveReport();
        try
        {
            Company = CurrentUserContext.CurrentCompany;
            Assembly asm = Assembly.GetAssembly(this.GetType());
            ar.DataInitialize += new EventHandler(ar_DataInitialize);
            ar.FetchData += new ActiveReport.FetchEventHandler(ar_FetchData);

            System.IO.Stream stre = asm.GetManifestResourceStream(asm.GetName().Name + ".GL.arActivity.rpx");

            using (XmlTextReader xr = new XmlTextReader(stre))
            {
                ar.LoadLayout(xr);
            }
    foreach (var itemAccRange in lstLedAccOrderBy)
            {
                List<M3.UDT.ReportDataGLActivityTransactions> lstReportData = new List<ReportDataGLActivityTransactions>();

                lstReportData = obj.GLActivityReport(Company, Property, itemAccRange.Account, StartDate, EndDate);
                var Acc = lstLedAcc.Where(x => x.Account == itemAccRange.Account).FirstOrDefault();
                foreach (var item in lstReportData)
                {
                    item.AccountNumber = itemAccRange.Account;


                    string AccName = string.Empty;
                    if (Acc != null)
                    {
                        AccName = Acc.FName;
                    }
                    item.AccountName = AccName;

                    if (Property != null)
                    {
                        item.CompanyName = Property.FName;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        item.CompanyName = Company.FName;
                    }

                    ((DataDynamics.ActiveReports.Label)ar.Sections["PageFooter"].Controls["lblDateTime"]).Value = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + " at " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
                    item.PostInvoiceDate = PostInvoiceDate;
                    item.JournalIDInvoiceNo = JournalIDInvoiceNo;
                    item.StartAcc = accountstart;
                    item.EndAcc = accountEnd;
                    item.TotalForAccountNumber = itemAccRange.Account;

                    item.PostDate = item.fPostDate.ToShortDateString();

                    if (item.DebitAmount == Convert.ToDecimal("0.00"))
                    {
                        item.DebitAmtDisplay = "";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        item.DebitAmtDisplay = Convert.ToString(item.DebitAmount);
                    }

                    if (item.CreditAmount == Convert.ToDecimal("0.00"))
                    {
                        item.CreditAmtDisplay = "";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        item.CreditAmtDisplay = Convert.ToString(item.CreditAmount);
                    }

                    item.period = string.Format(" {0} {1} {2} {3}", CultureManager.GetReportMessageString("IdPeriod"), item.fPostDate.Month, CultureManager.GetReportMessageString("IdOf"), item.fPostDate.Year);
                    item.Totalperiod = string.Format(" {0} {1} {2} {3}", CultureManager.GetReportMessageString("IdTotalPerid"), item.fPostDate.Month, CultureManager.GetReportMessageString("IdOf"), item.fPostDate.Year);
                    if (ShowAccountsHeader == "show")
                    {
                        item.ShowAccountsHeader = CultureManager.GetReportMessageString("IdShowAcc"); //"Show Accounts with no activity";
                    }
                    else if (ShowAccountsHeader == "hide")
                    {
                        item.ShowAccountsHeader = CultureManager.GetReportMessageString("IdHideAcc");//"Hide Accounts with no activity";
                    }
                    else if (ShowAccountsHeader == "zero")
                    {
                        item.ShowAccountsHeader = CultureManager.GetReportMessageString("IdShowAccBalZero"); //"Show Accounts with no activity if Begining Balance is not zero";
                    }
                    else
                    {

                    }
                    lstReportDataPrint.Add(item); //added by jitendra
                    lstReportDataPrint.GroupBy(elem => elem.fJEID).Select(group => group.First());
                }

            }
  ar.DataSource = lstReportDataPrint;
  ar.Run();
```

}

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Are there any async loading methods? In fact what does your loadreport method look like?

Comment: No there are no such type of method. LoadReport method is a simple method containing a nested foreach loop which takes too much time.

Comment: Can you show me the method please and I might be able to suggest something? Add it to the post, if possible.

Comment: I have edited the code to show the method.

Comment: The only thing I can think of here is to Parallel.ForEach the list processing.  Id hazard a guess that wont be blocking as long as the bind to the datasource though.  I had a quick look on the Website for the API I think you are using and they purport to be the fastest report software, surely they have async capability in this day and age?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a limitation of using Section Reports( In Active Reports 6 and below they were just called Active Reports ).   Section Reports using a "banded list" approach if you will and does not allow the report to be displayed until the query has been finished.

In Active Reports 7 and above we introduced the concept of Page Reports which allows for that behavior.  The Page Report can do this because of the way it is designed ( Page by Page approach ) so after page 1 is finished it displays it and the

1/# of total pages

The # of total pages starts at 1 and grows.

Comment: I there any way to do this in Active Reports 6?